# sql statment in email messge utl_mail.send

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I am sending emails true oracle apex which works fine. what i need however is to have an sql count statement in the message of the email.

what i have is

```
begin
   utl_mail.send(sender     => 'a@test.com',
                  recipients =>'a@test.com',
                  subject    => 'FileRequest',
                  message    =>  'select count(filenumber) where status is assigned' files from registry '||:p5_filenumber ||''||'  ' ||:p5_filename || ' has now been assigned to the ' || :p5_department || '');

end;
```

which obviously is not working

what i will like to see is

```
begin
   utl_mail.send(sender     => 'a@test.com',
                  recipients =>'a@test.com',
                  subject    => 'FileRequest',
                  message    =>  5 files from registry '||:p5_filenumber ||''||'  ' ||:p5_filename || ' has now been assigned to the ' || :p5_department || '');

end;
```

Answer (score 3):

Compute the value BEFORE sending the mail. Something like this:

```
declare
  l_cnt number;
  l_msg varchar2(200);
begin
  -- select number you're interested in
  select count(*)
    into l_cnt
    from some_table
    where some_conditions;

  -- compose the message
  l_msg := l_cnt ||' files from registry ...';

  -- send mail
  utl_mail.send(sender     => 'a@test.com',
                recipients => 'a@test.com',
                subject    => 'FileRequest',
                message    =>  l_msg);
end;
```